# Fitting of a Markov Switching Model

Tags: r, matlab, time-series, data-fitting, markov-models

I'm using the package `fMarkovSwitching` in R to do what I was trying to do here: [Fitting Markov Switching Models to data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281444/fitting-markov-switching-models-to-data-in-r).

However, I get another weird error message. I'm trying to replicate the example at page 12 (using my time series of log returns) of this paper: http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1714016

Here is the code I'm using:

```
library(tseries)

#Prices
ftse <- get.hist.quote(instrument="^FTSE", start="1984-01-03", end="2014-01-01", quote="AdjClose", compression="m")

#Log-returns
ftse.ret <- diff(log(ftse))
ftse.ret1 <- as.numeric(ftse.ret)

library(fMarkovSwitching)

dep <- ftse.ret1

constVec <- matrix(1,nrow=length(dep),ncol=1)

indep <- constVec

k <- 2

S <- c(1,1)

myModel<-MS_Regress_Fit(dep=dep,indep=indep,S=S,k=k,distIn = "Normal")
```

The error message I get is the following:

> Error in MS_Regress_Fit(dep = dep, indep = indep, S = S, k = k, distIn
>   = "Normal") :    The number of columns at indep should match the number of columns at S

The code I wrote is just a "translation" of the MATLAB example in the paper. If I modify `S` to have a match for the number of columns I still get the same error message, whereas if I modify  `indep` the output I get is wrong.

Edit: The package can be installed in R using the following command: `install.packages("fMarkovSwitching", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`

Comment: As you defined it, "S" is not a matrix, it is a vector. You need something like `S <- matrix(1, 1, 1)`. Off course, you have to check whether a 1x1 matrix make sense, as well as the accuracy of the result.

Comment: Defining `S` as you suggest (or simply assigning to it the value 1) the function seems to work properly.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether the function needs a `numeric` (dimension NULL) or a `matrix` (dimension 1 1).